# Value of weak force coupling constant

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, physical-constants, weak-interaction

I'm trying to get my head around the weak force coupling constant $\alpha_w$ but getting confused by different resources. Hyperphysics suggests it is tiny compared with the strong force coupling, ~$10^-6$ times the size, but Griffiths Introduction to Elementary Particles claims it is ~$1/30$, and so five times larger than $\alpha_{EM}$, which hyperphysics gives as the usual $1/137$.

Not sure what's going wrong here, but can anyone explain it to me? Thank you!

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/forces/couple.html#c4
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction#Properties

Comment: The value of the coupling constant actually changes with the renormalization scale, as described by K. Wilson's renormalization group, so there's no definite coupling constant.

Comment: Does that not apply to the strong and EM couplings? Is the weak force a special case?

Comment: Yes, it also applies to the strong and EM coupling constant...

Comment: OK, but we can still quote values of the couplings at a given scale. If we assume the same energy level for all of them, how does the strength of the weak coupling compare to the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here are](http://www.clab.edc.uoc.gr/materials/pc/proj/running_alphas.html) the inverses of the running coupling constants:

[image: running coupling]

Looking at the 1/coupling_constant it is true that the weak comes out as 1/30 to the 1/137 of the electromagnetic. In equation 5 of [this document](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/current/teach/module_home/px435/weak.pdf)   this factor is calculated , making as far as couplings go the weak four times stronger than the electromagnetic. BUT

> What makes the interaction so weak is the large mass of the relevant gauge bosons.

The number given in hyper physics, (and in the  table of Griffith*), compares decays of baryons to get the weak number of 10^-6 to the strong. This means that the  propagator of the W boson that initiates the [sigma decay](https://teachers.web.cern.ch/teachers/archiv/HST2002/feynman/examples.htm#Example%206) is contributing to the measured weakness of the decay, reducing the effect of the coupling constant.

So the 10^-6 is comparing lifetimes, and the 1/30 is the coupling constant in front of the matrix element that will calculate the lifetime.

---

- I found a pdf scan of [Griffiths](http://www.clab.edc.uoc.gr/materials/pc/proj/running_alphas.html) which on page 55 has  for [strength](http://www.clab.edc.uoc.gr/materials/pc/proj/running_alphas.html) : 10 10^-2 10^-13 10^-42 ( strong, em, weak, gravitational) and cautions that  strength depends on context ( particularly weak)is quoted as different in other sources. What page is this 1/ 30? as it is a scan and not searchable.

Comment: 315 in my edition, but comparing for your page 55, I think your version might be 4 pages behind, ie. I guess 311 for you. At the end of a calculation involving muons.

Comment: @KathrynBoast thanks. I see that it has the same argument and more extensively. So I guess the OP's wonder is at the value given in hyperphysics, which is the effective strength constant in decays. The agreement of the Higgs production at the LHC with the standard model must be within these calculations ( higher probabilities of producing a Higgs due to the high energy and the diminution of the mass of the  propagator effect). If there were discrepancies we would have heard a lot of noise.